# How to set the credentials in pygit2.clone_repository?

Tags: github, libgit2, pygit2

When I clone a repo from github by pygit2, it returns: 'OSError: Failed to send request: A security error occurred'
The code is simple,

```
import pygit2

username = 'MyGitHubUsername'
password = 'MyGitHubPassword'
cred = pygit2.UserPass(username, password)
repo = pygit2.clone_repository('https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2', 'C:/test', bare=False, credentials=cred)
```

But it doesn't work, is this right?

Comment: Did you try cloning with a different protocol, like ssh, just to see if that would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does using the exact same username and password work with git? If you have two-factor authentication activated, your normal password won't work. You have to create a new token and use that as your password.

Also make sure that the error *is* due to the credentials. "security error" could just as well mean that the HTTPS certificate of github.com is not recognised by your computer (looks like you might be using WinHTTP).